# Django : TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm trying to upgrade a django project from 1.8 to 1.10.

I have changed a view function from

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from sellmyland.settings import DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
from ipware.ip import get_ip
import json
from myapp.forms import myform


def index(request):


    form = myform()

    # return render('longform.html', {"form": form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

return render(request, 'longform.html', {'form': form})
```

settings.py:

```
# TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
#     # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
#     # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
#     # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
# )

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'DIRS': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'templates'),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # some options
        },
    },
]
```

You can see the commented out version in the code. I'm getting the error above. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "E:...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "E:...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "E:...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "E:...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "E:\ENVS\r3\sellmyland3\app1\views.py" in index
  30.     return render(request, 'longform.html', {'form': form})

File "E:...\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "E:...\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "E:...\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  25.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: longform.html
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new setting is TEMPLATES, not TEMPLATE_DIRS.